# Place square in front of other square

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas

Here is my code:

```
//ct is a canvas context for drawing stuff
//bw is image width, bh is image height
function drawBox() {
    ct.translate(x, y)
    ct.rotate(rot)
    ct.drawImage(box, -bw/2, -bh/2)
    ct.fillRect((-bw/2) + (50 * Math.sin(rot)), (-bh/2) - (50 * Math.cos(rot)), 20, 20)
    ct.rotate(-rot)
    ct.translate(-x, -y)
}
```

It is supposed to draw the box, and then place the rectangle 50 pixels in front of it. However, it is not working. The rectangle is rotating two times around the image for every time the image rotates once.

I've experimented a bit, and this code works:

```
function drawBox() {
    ct.drawImage(box, x, y)
    ct.fillRect((x) + (50 * Math.sin(rot)), (y) - (50 * Math.cos(rot)), 20, 20)
}
```

I have removed the rotation and changed the coordinates to `x` and `y`. If the above code works, why doesn't rotating it and then doing this code work? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you post a working fiddle, because you use lots of variables that we do not know what they hold..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved this. I realized the problem was that I was rotating around the wrong point when drawing my other box, so I used this code:

```
function drawBox() {
    ct.translate(x, y)
    ct.rotate(rot)
    ct.drawImage(box, -halfbw, -halfbh)
    ct.rotate(-rot)
    ct.translate(-x, -y)
    if (sCount > 0) {
        sCount --
        ct.translate(x, y+halfbh)
        ct.rotate(rot+PI)
        ct.fillRect((halfbh * Math.sin(rot)), (halfbh * Math.cos(rot))+halfbh, 10, 50)
        ct.rotate(-rot-PI)
        ct.translate(-x, -y-halfbh)
    }
}
```

(I added a couple of irrelevant things, like `sCount`, but this is essentially what the problem was.) I had to un-translate and un-rotate so I could re-translate and rotate to where the second box would be at the right place.